# Special Relativity metric and imaginary sentence

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor

we know that the simple form of the metric in the special relativity is like this: $ds^2 = dr^2 - (cdt)^2$ that in this metric $dr^2 = dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2 .$ I want to ask why we minus the time sentence? I know the mathematical reasons but I wanna know what happens in nature and reality by minus of the time sentence.

Comment: There are no mathematical reasons for a particular metric. Mathematics allows all kinds of metrics. So what do you mean when you say you "know the mathematical reasons"?

Comment: Target is not about the math totally.goal is about understanding why we have imaginary time and minus the time sentence from other sums

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107443/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/304799/2451 and links therein.

Comment: It is really helpful.thank you.